# Framing a Soffit with Construction Screws

Tags: framing, screws, soffit

I am building a soffit around my HVAC in the garage. I still have to remove the dry wall from the floor truss so I included a pic of an exposed area. The question is I do not have a framing nailer and I want to build a soffit. Would it be okay to use something like the [SPAX® PowerLags® T-Star Washer Head, Interior Construction Screws, Yellow Zinc](https://spax.us/products/powerlags/t-star-washer-head-yellow-zinc-powerlags)

[image: Picture of HVAC/Area of framing]
[image: Picture of Floor Trusses]

Answer (score 2):

Construction screws will be fine. Depending on how dry the lumber is, you might want to predrill and countersink. (You’ll almost certainly want to do that at the very ends, which are prone to splitting.) Of the screws I’ve used over the years, Spax are very good.